# Select 1:n e n:1 utilizando JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

Boa noite,
Estou tentando realizar um select entre tabelas 1:n e n:1 utilizando jpql

tabela categoira

```
@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoria")
private List<ProdutoCategoria> produtoCategorias;
```

tabela ProdutoCategoria

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idCategoria", nullable = false)
    private Categoria categoria;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idProduto", nullable = false)
    private Produto produto;
```

tabela Produto

```
@NotBlank
@Column(nullable = false)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "produto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ProdutoCategoria> categorias;
```

jpql

```
StringBuilder jpqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        jpqlBuilder.append("select new br.com.ecommerce.domain.dto.ProdutoDTO( ");
        jpqlBuilder.append("  cat.nome, ");
        jpqlBuilder.append("  count(pro) ");
        jpqlBuilder.append(") ");
        jpqlBuilder.append("from Produto pro ");
        jpqlBuilder.append("join pro.categorias.categoria cat  ");
        jpqlBuilder.append("group by cat.nome ");
```

com essa consulta eu espero saber quantos produtos cada categoria possui
ex:
Categoria Caçados tem 3 produtos registrados

Construtor DTO

```
public ProdutoDTO(String categoria, Long quantidadeProdutos) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.quantidadeProdutos = quantidadeProdutos;
    }
```

ao tentar da forma como esta, da esse erro

> org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference
>   collection [produto0_.id.categorias] with element property reference
>   [categoria]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi assim, perdi um bom tempo por causa disto ¬¬"

```
StringBuilder jpqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
jpqlBuilder.append("select new br.com.ecommerce.domain.dto.ProdutoDTO( ");
jpqlBuilder.append("  cat.categoria.nome, ");
jpqlBuilder.append("  count(pro) ");
jpqlBuilder.append(") ");
jpqlBuilder.append("from Produto pro ");
jpqlBuilder.append(" join pro.categorias cat  ");
jpqlBuilder.append("group by cat.categoria.nome ");
```